# Swift - Only Update count label in UITableView not all objects when like button is pressed

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uilabel

```
@IBAction func topButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
    object.incrementKey("count")
    object.saveInBackground()

    self.tableView.reloadData() 

    //I'm not sure how to change this code to update only the label.

    NSLog("Top Index Path \(hitIndex?.row)")
    sender.enabled = false


}
```

This code is for a like button that updates a counter on Parse and then refreshes all the data in the tableView. I was wondering how can I only update the label. The label is on the same view as the like button and called "count" with no quotations. I want it so that when I press like the number in the count label in the TableViewCell increases instead of all the tableview cells refreshing.

Comment: Is the like button on the table view cell? Is user able to like individual cell?

Comment: the like button is on the uitableviewcell. in the cell is a button and right below it a label that records how many likes there are. Yes the user can press like in each cell.

Answer (score 0):

In each table view cell, you have to keep a reference to the label or a tag in the cell and to know your cell hierarchy.
For an UIButton and an UILabel you have to do (you can even add an animation to the label change if you want):

```
let cell = button.superview.superview.superview
cell.labelName.text = String(count + 1)
```

Else you can also do that, which is a lot cleaner, but different, you only reload the changed row:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([hitIndex], withRowAnimation:None 
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
Like before

Answer (score 0):

As you have individual button in UITableViewCell and I assume you might have an xib with Swift class for it.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    //Linked to the like button in xib
    @IBOutlet weak var likeCountLabel: UILabel!

    var likeCount = 0

    //Linked to the Touch Up Inside event of like button
    @IBAction func likeMe() {

        //As this method is in the cell so you do not have worry about
        //indexPath.
        likeCount++
        likeCountLabel.text = String(likeCount)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        //
    }
}
```

The point is you could move your code to your custom UITableViewCell rather than in to your UIViewController. That way it will be quite easy for you to manage.